# chipTan in combination with bank's portal or mobile application

Tags: authentication, banks

I use chipTAN for authentication in banking-context because I think it's the better second factor.

Till now I use the bank´s portal via a browser on my PC.
In future I want to use the mobile application provided by the bank.

Now is the question is the mobile application more insecure than the bank's portal?

If this isn´t the case, is there a difference between use the bank's portal via a browser on my PC or via a browser on my mobile phone?

Comment: Depends on the bank. Often the mobile "app" just displays the mobile website of the online banking in a convenient way.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to say if the app is more or less secure than the web portal without access to security testing data, there is no default 'x is more secure than y' scenario. It depends on many factors.

There may be a difference between the portal you use on your PC and the portal you use on your phone.  Web applications will often deliver a different UI based on the user agent and it is possible that some of these underwent different levels of security engineering and security testing. Again though, there is no way we can tell you without carrying out a security audit of the application.